# Android video Player for video streaming (currently using ExoPlayer )

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-video-player

In android application I am showing videos using **ExoPlayer** , I am facing memory issues and slow video rendering, if there is any alternative android native video player please suggest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post log or error ?

Comment: It may help to describe what format are you trying to render (size, bitrate, etc.) and how you are testing - which device & OS version.

Comment: i am looking for ExoPlayer alternative or any video player library available on github which support network video streaming

Comment: Please define what `network video streaming` is. As reference here are the native Android supported formats: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html#core You say you are facing memory problem and slow video rendering - in comparison to what - how are you testing.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify any special requirements - have you tried [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)? I had good experience with it.

Answer (score -1):

**You can use below code to play .m3u8 file before initializing your exoplayer:-**

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();

String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(context, "APPLICATION_NAME");

DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(
                userAgent, null,
                DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
                1800000,
                true);

HlsMediaSource mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource(Uri.parse(mediaUrl),dataSourceFactory, 1800000,mHandler, null);

if (mediaUrl != null) {
    videoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
    videoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
}
```